# Setting environment variables in Springboot, Gradle and SpringBootTest?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, junit, spring-boot-test

I'm running unit tests and the underlying code relies on the presence of some environment variables. *Not* application properties, but actual system environment variables. If they're not present, the app will die.

## Gradle Test Block

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat "full"
        showExceptions = true
        showStackTraces = true
        showStandardStreams = true
    }
    environment "APP_ID", "id"
    environment "STATSD_HOST", "localhost"
    environment "STATSD_PORT", "8125"
}
```

## Unit Test

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(value = "classpath:application-test.properties")
public class MyCoolTest {
...
```

But I'm still getting an NPE on this value. This works if I force the env variable in intellij IDE explicitly, but I don't want to do it that way. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you run the test? A part of IntelliJ or with `gradle test`?

Comment: intellij, works with gradle